# How to not hard code size of image in HTML? (Code Included)

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<style type="text/css">
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .abcd{
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<body>
<div class="abcd">
    <img src="color.jpg" >
</div>
</body>
```

resolution of color.jpg is 2560x1440 and screen is 1920x1080. The image exceeds screen. If I hardcode it for a resolution it might be a problem for other screen sizes. 
I'm looking for "match_parent" of Android XML type of thing so that image takes only size of the screen.

Thank you, everyone, who took out their precious time to answer my question. I'm indebted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use percentage on the `width`.

But you have to go up from `HTML` to define the parent’s percentage.

```
html,body {
    width:100%
}

.abcd {
    width:100%;
}

img {
    width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to set a percentage for the `width`. If the parent has `position: relative` the percentage will correspond to the parent's size, so `100%` would match the parent width.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Set css to img tag instead.

Check out this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z22z5b5u/3/) code.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```